# google visualization data.addRow - get data out of html data attribute

Tags: arrays, google-visualization

I have data inside a data attribute, like so:

```
<div class="dashboard-module" data-rows="new Date(2013,10,04),12,"OR"##new Date(2013,10,17),2,"OR"##new Date(2013,10,09),2,"CA""></div>
```

Im trying to split this string up and use it in the data.addRow function:

```
      rows = el.data('rows');
      rowsarray = rows.split('##');
      // Error: Row given with size different than 3 (the number of columns in the table).
      $.each(rowsarray, function(index, value) {
        data.addRow( [value] );
      });
      // the following works
      data.addRow([new Date(2013,10,04),12,"OR"]);
      data.addRow([new Date(2013,10,09),2,"CA"]);
      data.addRow([new Date(2013,12,12),14,"AL"]);
```

I guess the commas inside the new date are being counted as different parts of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the double-quotes inside your `data-rows` attribute are escaped (otherwise the HTML is malforned).

When you call `rowsarray = rows.split('##');`, you are getting an array of strings, like this:

```
[
    'new Date(2013,10,04),12,"OR"',
    'new Date(2013,10,17),2,"OR"',
    'new Date(2013,10,09),2,"CA"'
]
```

not an array of arrays.  If you want to store your data in an HTML attribute, your best bet is to use a JSON-compatible format.  The problem then becomes storing dates, since Date objects are not JSON-compatible, but that is easy to work around.  Store your data like this instead:

```
[["Date(2013,10,04)",12,"OR"],["Date(2013,10,17)",2,"OR"],["Date(2013,10,09)",2,"CA"]]
```

I did two things with the `data-rows` attribute: first, I changed the dates from a format like `new Date(2013,10,17)` to a string like `"Date(2013,10,17)"`.  Second, I converted the string to a JSON string representation of an array of arrays (which uses the standard javascript array brackets `[` and `]`).  Note that JSON requires the use of double-quotes for all internal strings, so you must either escape all internal strings to use with the `data-rows` attribute, or use single-quotes around the `data-rows` attribute string (eg: `data-rows='<string>'`).

You can then parse that string for entry into your DataTable:

```
rows = JSON.parse(el.data('rows'));
// convert date strings to Date objects
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var dateStr = rows[i][0];
    var dateArr = dateStr.substring(5, dateStr.length - 1).split(',');
    rows[i][0] = new Date(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2]);
}
data.addRows(rows);
```

Comment: Hey man, wonder if I can pick your brains quickly please. When I first load this function it works fine but Im also refreshing the module when it is resized.

If I log the dateStr the first time it looks like ["Date(2012-02-15)"] which works. When I run the function again I see [Thu Mar 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)]

Somehow the second time it is seeing the date in the data attribute as a date rather than a string

Comment: How are you adding the date to the data attribute?

Comment: The data attribute gets set in xsl.

Comment: Are you updating the data attribute in-page?  If not, then you don't need to parse the data rows again.

Comment: Nope not updating the data attribute at all. The function currently parses the data attribute each time it is run. The function doesn't change the value of the data attribute though so not sure what is happening here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47996/discussion-between-mark-steggles-and-asgallant)